# Jquery .load from same page and insert in different ids

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do jquery ajax load from page and want to insert in different ids

**Options Page**

```
$('#ipc').load('/dashboard/details/options #eventdata1');
$('#cou').load('/dashboard/details/options #eventdata1');
```

**HTML Part**

```
<div id="eventdata1">1</div>
<div id="eventdata2">2</div>
```

First event loads fine but firebug shows following error for second load each time

```
"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://localhost/dashboard/details/options"
```

**Update 1**

When I try to update div from different pages it works fine like

```
$('#ipc').load('/dashboard/details/page1 #eventdata1');
$('#cou').load('/dashboard/details/page2 #eventdata1');
```

**Update 2**

```
    $.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
});
```

Set cache to false, now it work sometimes.

Comment: the error message show that you has loss connection.

Comment: Why is it happening if I load divs from same page only?

Comment: "403 Forbidden" mean you have no access to that page.

Comment: It seems to be web page access problem. Try the same url directly to the browser address bar. Showing the 403 error?

Comment: But my first load statement is working from same page, error comes when i call 2nd load

Answer (score 1):

Access to the resource identified by the URL is forbidden for some reason. **[Source](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E403.html)**

Comment: Why is it happening if I load divs from same page only? There is no auth component on my page, I am aware of 403 error...

Comment: seems permission issue, but strange you are getting it fine once.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#ipc,#cou').load('/dashboard/details/options #eventdata1');
```

try loading at the same time if it works

Comment: Problem is I want to insert #ipc content in #eventdata1 and #cou content in #eventdata2

Comment: Might be a problem with cacheing then maybe this works $('#ipc').load('/dashboard/details/options #eventdata1?'+Math.random());
$('#cou').load('/dashboard/details/options #eventdata2?'+Math.random());

Comment: Problem persists even after setting global ajax cache to false...
Now sometime it work and sometime it doesn't